# Javascript function to sum of columns (into google dataTable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, sum, google-visualization

Here I have google visualisation datatable:
[image]

How I can add here new Row and on postion [0] to put string "Sum" in position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9nd9.jpg) will be 10, in position [2] will be 17, as sum of columns...

I start to write code but I'n not going anywhere ...

I try:

```
data.addRow();
        for (var x=1, maxcol=data.getNumberOfColumns(); x < maxcol; x++) {
            for y=1, maxrow=data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrow; y++) {
        //WHAT NEXT ???
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var group = google.visualization.data.group(data, [{
    type: 'number',
    column: 0,
    modifier: function () {return 0;}
}], [{
    type: 'number',
    column: 1,
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
}, {
    type: 'number',
    column: 2,
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
}]);

data.addRow(['Sum', group.getValue(0, 1), group.getValue(0, 2)]);
```

**[Edit - added code to handle an arbitrary number of columns]**

```
var groupColumns = [];
for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    groupColumns.push({
        type: 'number',
        column: i,
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    });
}

var group = google.visualization.data.group(data, [{
    type: 'number',
    column: 0,
    modifier: function () {return 0;}
}], groupColumns);

var row = ['Sum'];
for (var i = 1; i < group.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
     row.push(group.getValue(0, i));
}

data.addRow(row);
```

Comment: ok, thanks nice, thanks, but what if I dont know how much column I have ?

Comment: Etc. I column create dinamicly from database and column are not every time the same, so some times I have 3 sometimes I have 5, sometimes I have 10 columns ... so I need to create for loop ?

Comment: Will you need to do different kinds of aggregation on each column, or will they all be sums?